# TYPO3 - Multi-Language - Fallback

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fallback, typo3-8.x

I have this Language-ID´s for the TYPO3 Backend:

```
0 = DE 
1 = EN 
2 = ES
3 = CN
```

And now i need a Fallback for the Language ES and CN to the Content EN (id=1).

How can i do this?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

`config.sys_language_mode` with `content_fallback` is your friend. Look here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/Setup/Config/#sys-language-mode

Comment: my test:
    sys_language_overlay = 1
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback; 1
dont work

Comment: mybe a bug in the T3 Core ? https://git.higidi.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/commit/113943c6d0d29a51ad2d3b13b4850b001fde1829

Comment: now it works for content, but not for menu or news. the menu is for default/id=0 :(

Comment: @SebastianSchmal, If "sys_language_overlay = 1 sys_language_mode = content_fallback; 1" is not worked. Then how do you solve it for the content? I am asking because I am also struggling with this. If you have no problem, can I know how you solve it. Thanks